# Use Twig to populate JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, json, twig

I am passing an array to Twig, and wish Twig to json_encode it and assign it to a JavaScript variable.  When doing so, it is not well formed, and appears as:

```
[&quot;one&quot;,&quot;two&quot;,&quot;three&quot;]
```

For my immediate case, the data is not user provided and is assumed safe, however, I might have other occasions where this is not the case.

How is this task best performed.

PHP File

```
<?php

require_once '../../../vendor/autoload.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

try {
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
        'debug' => true
    ));
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
    echo $twig->render('json.html', array('data'=>array('one','two','three')));

} catch (Exception $e) {
    die ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

json.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var data={{ data|json_encode() }}
            console.log(data);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>{{ dump(data) }}</pre>
        <pre>{{ dump(data|json_encode()) }}</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "three"
}

string(21) "["one","two","three"]"

SyntaxError: syntax error
var data=[&quot;one&quot;,&quot;two&quot;,&quot;three&quot;]
```

Comment: @Ohgodwhy.  Agree.  Sorry for the duplicated post.  Interesting, the selected answer was wrong.  Furthermore, a comment to the more correct answer indicated it might be prone to XSS.  As I indicated in my original post, the data might be user provided.  Comments?  Thank you

Comment: The answer is correct, it's just in the comments instead of his physical answer (I dislike when that occurs, too). As far as the XSS is concerned, you could just pass in an argument to `json_encode()` such as `json_encode(constant('JSON_HEX_TAG'))` which will convert all `< and >` to the `\u003c` and `\u003E`. There's probably a better way in twig, but I"m not well versed in twig to give a direct answer, and it may be better to create a new question

Comment: Have you trie dusing the filter `raw` ? Twig by default encodes your output, so you don't have to worry about XSS. Obviously, you have to be 400% sure that this data is trusted before outputting raw data. Try `{{ variables | raw }}`